# Why is LI not expanding over content

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list and within each list item I have a div, and contained in the div I have an image, the div is correctly expanding around the image, but the containing LI is not.

See my fiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/caseylmanus/VL4HX/

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
   <div data-role="header">
     <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="featuredApps">
            <ul>
                <li style="border:1px solid red;">
                    <div class="featuredApp">
                        <img style="width:100%" src="http://www.marketcircle.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/app-feature-1.png" />
                    </div>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position='fixed'>
     <h4>Footer</h4>

</div>
```

What can I do to the LI to make it expand to the right height and width so the div is completely contained within it and the image is completely contained in the div?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the position:absolute from .featuredApp

I would also remove the width from .featuredApp and place it on the li

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px solid #c00;
    width:33.33%;
}
.featuredApp {

}
.featuredApp img {
    border-radius:9px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/VL4HX/20/

Comment: I cannot remove the position:absolute because I intend to animate the images in the list.